# hide a pseudo-element from a screenreader?

Tags: css, accessibility, pseudo-element, screen-readers

I am using `:before` pseudo-elements bound to particular classes to add symbols in front of `p` tags, with CSS like this:

```
td > p.markerclass1:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1rem;
    content: '*';
}
```

I am using this in a Wordpress theme where the user can select that class for a `p` tag in the editor, in order to to put that symbol to the left of the current paragraph.

However, the website should be accessible, and the screenreader (at least NVDA, with which I am testing this) is reading that pseudo element and the included symbol, which I don't want. But since this element is not in the HTML code, I cannot add `aria-hidden = 'true'` to hide it from screenreaders.

Any idea what i could do to get the screenreader to ignore those pseudo-elements?

Comment: This might help: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/hide-content-in-css-pseudo-elements-from-screen-readers/

Answer (score 19):

Know this is old, but recently had to answer this too and [eventually found a better answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47451397/2144578)

pseudo-elements; alternative text can be indicated after a `/`:

```
td > p.markerclass1:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1rem;
  content: "*";
  content: "*" / ""; 
}
```

In this case the blank alt text will cause this content to be ignored.

Note [not all browsers support this syntax](https://a11ysupport.io/tests/tech__css__css_generated_content_alt) (basically just Chromium based browsers at this time of writing) so make sure you add a fallback first that works for all browsers and is only overridden by those that support this new syntax as well. Otherwise, without this fallback, browsers like Safari just ignore the unrecognised CSS line and fail to display anything when you use an `/` for alt text!

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the `speak` property:

CSS:

```
td > p.markerclass1:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1rem;
    content: '*';
    speak: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I found something about this on W3C, but nothing on caniuse. Would you know about its browser support?

Comment: After a quick check using this page http://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/speak.php it seems, Chrome, Safari and Opera support it (tried only Mac), Firefox and IE/Edge don't... Not enough for my purposes...

Comment: As far as I know, it's not well supported and the only alternative is aria-hidden. If you can figure out a way to implement it, along with the speak property, it will cover everything.

Comment: @Johannes I think an alternative solution would be to use a list and maybe add a " * " as your list style, I can provide the code for that if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, but I already found another solution, using an absolutely positioned element which I add with jQuery (and which has the aria-hidden attribute), and using the pseudo-element only in the editor styles, where it doesn't have to be accessible.

Comment: Sure. I still feel that a styled list would be much simpler to implement though. But either way, sorry I couldn't be more help, and thanks for the upvote

Comment: OP did you notice a difference with and without that property in aforementioned browsers? With VO I guess? Never heard (ha) of an implementation of this CSS Aural media property (and Assistive Technologies like screen readers are _screen_ readers)

Comment: Looks like the speak CSS property is now deprecated: https://www.cssportal.com/css-properties/speak.php

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-element inheritates from the main class their visibility for screen and screenreaders.

For instance, the following code will hide everything including the `*`

```
p:before {content:'*'}
p {display:none}
```

If you want the content of the pseudo element not to be read, you have to use an unprounounceable replacement like an UTF-8 equivalent :

```
td > p.markerclass1:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1rem;
    content: "\2022";
}
```

EDIT: `\2022` announces "bullet" with NVDA while another code like `\2023` for instance announces nothing

Comment: re unpronouncable: yes, I also had tried that, but that way it still is presented as an empty element, not skipped/ignored, which is only "semi-usable" But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

The scenario was "Send Mail" link associated with "Click Here To" text, but Screen Reader reads the whole text, but i want it to read only "Send mail".

Here i have solved that issue using "aria-label" attribute.

```css
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a::before 
{
    content:"Click here to - ";
    color:Black;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com" target="_top" aria-label="Send Mail">Send Mail</a>
```

Hope this will work for you guys.