# How to hide CSS generated content from screen readers without HTML markup?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

How would one hide CSS certain generated content (used for pure styling) from screen reader? Is it possible without using HTML hacks like `aria-hidden`?

E.g. I use code `content: '·';` for separating stuff. I've checked facebook & other big players but they all seem to use spans with `aria-hidden`:

`<span aria-hidden="true">·</span>`

Does it mean it’s not possible currently?

Comment: What do you mean by hack? The whole point of `aria-hidden` is so that screen readers and similar ignore it.

Comment: Screen readers should be able to rely on HTML of the page only, no JS or CSS. So if you want to hide something from them, you need to use an HTML attribute. It is not a hack, what else you have in mind?

Comment: I consider it a hack because you can’t achieve the needed functionality with CSS only and have to edit the HTML. And if you can’t hide it from CSS directly, that leaves :before / :after pretty unusable in half of the cases.

Comment: Are there no media queries for screen readers?

Comment: @Mr Lister: The speech media type exists, but I'm not sure if it (or its predecessor aural) is implemented by any screen readers.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to do this with either the screen media type, or speak: none on your pseudo-elements. But, as mentioned, how much of css-speech and aural CSS is implemented is unclear.

Comment: @MrLister Screen reader detection has never been considered good practice.

Comment: This might help: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/hide-content-in-css-pseudo-elements-from-screen-readers/

Answer (score 15):

For future references, [note that according to CSS Content Module Level 3 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#accessibility):

> Generated content should be searchable, selectable, and available to assistive technologies. The content property applies to speech and generated content must be rendered for speech output.

It's also stated that :

> If the pseudo-element is purely decorative and its function is covered elsewhere, setting alt to the empty string can avoid reading out the decorative element.

This concernes `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements;  alternative text might be indicated after a `/`:

```
.expandable::before {
  content: "\25BA" / ""; 
}
```

For CSS2, you may use unpronounceable UTF-8 elements in order to be sure that the elements won't be announced.

For instance, when you use the code:

```
.bullet {
    content: "\2022";
}
```

`\2022` (bullet : •) announces "bullet" with NVDA while another code like `\2023` (triangular bullet : ‣) announces nothing

Comment: Also, I found this article useful «The CSS "content" property accepts alternative text» https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/css-content-accepts-alternative-text/

Comment: That’s very interesting, and I now remember that I experimented with alternative text from CSS a long time ago (:
Unfortunately it doesn’t have good support: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_content_alt_text

Answer (score 1):

The answer is short and simple: it's impossible.

BY the way, CSS-generated contents may or may not be spoken depending on the browser and screen reader used, so you don't know for sure whether it will be spoken or not (don't use this to give important information).

Additionally, about the already answer posted above: you shouldn't rely on the fact that a given character is unrecognized and thus perhaps ignored, for at least three reasons:

- VoiceOver sometimes says "unpronouncible";
- Maybe tomorrow your unrecognized character will become recognized
- Users can register special characters in their pronunciation dictionary

It's a personal point of view, but I think that CSS-generated content is a conception defect: it should never be used, and it should never have been invented, according to the base separation principle: Content = HTML, Presentation = CSS, Interactivity = JavaScript.

Sadly it's too late now.

Comment: Makes sense. I wouldn’t agree on CSS generation content is defect, but I would agree it’s breaking separation principle. If screen readers ignored the generated text, it could be used purely for decoration as it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is intended that pseudo content is read out by screen readers.

Media queries "speech" (deprecated) and "aural" are also not supported, which would have been a way to "hide" pseudo content.

Here is a good overview of what is supported by a big number of screen readers (under "Expected to fail"): https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/content/